# How can I add an expression inside the $mail-> Body in phpMailer?

Tags: php, phpmailer

The phone number in a form isn't required. I would like to hide the label if the phone number field didn't collect any data.

Something like this in theory?

```
$mail->Body = "
  <p><strong>Name: </strong> $full_name</p> 
  <p><strong>Email: </strong> $email</p>". 
  if ($phone !== ''){
    echo '<p><strong>Phone: </strong> $phone</p>';
  } else {
    echo '';
  } . "
  <p><strong>Message: </strong> $message</p> 
";
```

But is not the right syntax. How can I do this? p.s. a Ternary expression would even be cleaner, but it didn't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't echo, append content:

```php
$mail->Body = "<p><strong>Name: </strong> $full_name</p> 
  <p><strong>Email: </strong> $email</p>";
 
  if ($phone !== ''){
    $mail->Body .= '<p><strong>Phone: </strong> $phone</p>';
  }

  $mail->Body .= '<p><strong>Message: </strong> $message</p>';
```

Comment: Picked this one for simplicity. It never occurred to me to split the body  :facepalm:

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative, which works better in some situations:

```
if( $phone )
    $phone = "<p><strong>Phone: </strong>$phone</p>";
$mail->Body = "<p><strong>Name: </strong>$full_name</p> 
  <p><strong>Email: </strong>$email</p>
  $phone
  <p><strong>Message: </strong>$message</p>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "
  <p><strong>Name: </strong> $full_name</p> 
  <p><strong>Email: </strong> $email</p>". 
  ($phone !== '' ? '<p><strong>Phone: </strong> $phone</p>' : '').
"<p><strong>Message: </strong> $message</p>";
$mail->Body = $string;
```

This is easier. Make the string first then append the string to the body of the mail.

Comment: This code is not correct.  The precedence of dot "." is higher than that of the ternary operator (?:), so everything up to the `?` will be parsed first.  You would need to use parentheses.  That's why ternary is so dangerous; it's very difficult to tell from a quick reading how it will be interpreted.  Plus, despite your description, this does not "append the string to the body of the mail".  It overwrites it.